# $mysqli->change_user returns Access denied NO password

Tags: mysql-5.7, php, mysqli

PHP 8.2.14

MySQL 5.7.23-23 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 23, Revision 500fcf5

This is on a shared webhost with CPanel.

I'm importing this test script on page load...

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "<username1>", "<password1>", "<dbname>");
$conn->change_user("<username2>", "<password2>", "<dbname>");
```

If I remove line 2, there is no error. This is true with either set of credentials, so I know for a fact that I'm passing the correct credentials and that they work. Since I'm passing the strings directly, I can't see how a no password error could be possible.

```
[24-Jan-2024 21:11:56 America/Boise] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user '<username2>'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home1/user/public_html/site/folder/script.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/user/public_html/site/folder/script.php(69): mysqli->change_user('<username2>', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), '<dbname>')
#1 /home1/user/public_html/site/index.php(47): require_once('/home1/user...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home1/user/public_html/site/folder/script.php on line 69
```

Comment: I added an issue and received a response at GitHub from PHP. They said that this was likely caused by a bug in this version of MySQL ( https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102266). Since I can't update MySQL on this host, I am unable to verify if upgrading would resolve it. PHP advised me that change_user is equivalent to calling $conn->connect() - the only difference that I must specify the server. I'm doing that now, and It's working fine.